# How to display an input like stackoverflow answer box

Tags: javascript, django, markdown

I'm working on a Django chat app and I want a `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">` with the markdown format, like this own input, that I can format code, put images, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like TinyMCE, however just do a search on Google for JavaScript WYSIWYG editor. Some will come with markdown plugins.